# Compiler tries to locate methods in one library, that exists in another library (CS0234)?

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with an old library I am trying to re-activate (use again). I have a library called "PLToolbox" in which I have multiple namespaces (e.g. "PLToolbox.FileIO", "PLToolbox.Graphics", "PLToolbox.MathNumeric"). As said all these namespaces live in my PLToolbox library (one file, many namespaces).

I now tied to add an old library (one library containing one namespace). This library/namespace is called "PLToolbox.SQLite", and I have added a new "PLToolbox.SQLite" project to my "PLToolbox" solution, and it compiles just fine and everything is working as expected (building my solution it both generates a "PLToolbox.dll" and a "PLToolbox.SQLite.dll").

My problem is the application using these namespaces (both referencing "PLToolbox" and "PLToolbox.SQLite"). When ever I build this project (a Winform application), where I use classes from the "PLToolbox.SQLite" library, it generates an error message saying: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'PLToolbox' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The actual line giving this error message is "using PLToolbox.SQLite;", and as the error states, it tries to look for the "PLToolbox.SQLite" namespace within the "PLToolbox" library, even though this namespace is only defined within the "PLToolbox.SQLite" library. If if remove the "using PLToolbox.SQLite;" from my project and in stead prefix all lines (accessing this library) with "PLToolbox.SQLite." it compiles fine, but this is a drag. Likewise I am sure renaming my "PLToolbox.SQLite" into "PLToolboxSQLite" (or something else) would "fix the problem", but this should work some how with the name is has now?

I am sure this is how I used these two libraries together, back in a previous version of Visual Studio (using version 2.0 of the .Net Framework with Visual Studio 2003/2005). Now I am running with Visual Studio 2015 and .Net Framework 4.0, so perhaps this is the cause? or simply I forgot to do something I did back then?

Comment: "as the error states, it tries to look for the "PLToolbox.SQLite" namespace within the "PLToolbox" library" - but that's **not** what the error states. It says it cannot find it within the `PLToolbox` *namespace*. Namespaces and assembly names are only related by convention.

Comment: I remember running into such sort of issues when the .NET Framework version did not match between the application and its reference. Check whether the version matches.

Answer (score 0):

My bad :-( It turned out that my "PLToolbox.SQLite" was targeting .Net framevork "V4.52.0" (whereas my "PLToolbox" and my Winforms application using both libraries were targeting "V4). As soon as I changed "PLToolbox.SQLite" into "V4" and re-build everything was fine.